# Create Resource group in Terraform in sequence

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create a resource group in Azure with the help of Terraform and while creating it, I want to follow a naming convention.
Let's say, I have created a resource group **rg-dev-001** with the help of terraform. And if I run the terraform script again next time then It should create **rg-dev-002.** How can I achieve it in terraform?

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "rg-dev-xxx"
  location = "West Europe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to create resource groups in sequence in Terraform :

```
terraform {

  required_version = ">=0.12"
  
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  count = number of resource groups to be created
  name = "rg-dev-00${count.index+1}"
  location = "LocationName"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I dont want to create it all at the same time. Lets say, rg-dev-005 is created in last terraform run and If I run terraform again then it automatically create it rg-dev-005 + 1 means- rg-dev-006. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @AshishKumar - That is not how Terraform works. If you run it again, it will make sure the existing resource exits or it will be recreated. Read the docs on the purpose of Terraform.

Comment: But if someone wants to follow sequencing, what we can do to achieve it?